# Tab grouping and tab colouring: How to get this feature to tabs opened from my web page irrespective of browser

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, frontend

I wrote a code to display a bunch of hyperlinks in my web page.

```
<td id="formType" class="center" width="75">
<a href="${d.getURL()}" title="${d.getTitle()}">
<c:out value="${d.getType()}" />
</a>
</td>
```

When I click on hyperlink on browser it is showing the clicked hyperlink in the same tab.

I modified as follows to show it in new tab.

```
<td id="formType" class="center" width="75"> 
<a href="${d.getURL()}" title="${d.getTitle()}" target="_blank">
<c:out value="${d.getType()}" /> 
</a>
</td>
```

After this modification I am able to open the clicked hyper link in new tab.

Now I want to group tabs. and colour tabs. IE 8 has this cool feature. Is this browser dependent feature. Can I get these features to my tabs irrespective of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Tab handling is done on a browser level. Although you could write a browser extension that would work with your page, you can't just write in-page javascript to change the behavior of the browser. In your code 'target="_blank"' is what causes the creation of a new tab, or if the browser does not support tabs, it will default to a new window. You can not, however, affect how the browser handles that new tab or window. If you just want tab grouping, colorizing, and other features, there are several great extensions for both Chrome and Firefox.